# We have private function app while Deploying the function HTTP trigger using VS code we are getting 403 error

Tags: azure, function, private

We have function App which is created using Private Endpoint and Private Vnet Integration.
We are trying to Deploy the code using VS code
While on the Deployment phase We are getting 403 Error.

Our Expectation is creating function using VS code

Comment: I would suggest creating an Azure VM in the Virtual Network and then using the VS code from that VM to deploy the Azure Function.

Comment: The complete error is below:  Error : Error -403 Forbidden "The Web App  you have attempted to reach has blocked your access

Comment: Function App and The VM which has VS code both are peered. So Assume it has connectivity correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Are both in the same subnet?

Comment: Both of them in the different subnet it has been peered, one thing i noticed when i do NS lookup from that VM to function APp Private link its still resolving public IP. Note: I have disabled the public access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced your requirement by creating a simple ***python function app*** in ***VScode*** and deployed to the ***Azure function app*** which is created using ***Private Endpoints*** and ***Private Vnet Integration***.

**Steps followed:**

- Create a ***VNET*** and ***Function app*** in Azure.
- Open your `Function app=>Networking=>Private Endpoints`, *create private endpoint, Add=>Express*:

[image]

- ***Navigate to*** `Networking=> VNet Integration=> Add virtual network Integration`:

[image]

- ***Make sure VNet integration and endpoints configured properly in the function app and necessary firewall rules are in place to allow traffic to and from the private endpoint.***

[image]

- ***Deployed Function to Azure Function app through VS Code:***

[image]

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

- ***Could access the function app without any issues:***

[image]

Comment: As you said we have setup the same in our environment but we got below error messages 403 Forbidden "The Web App you have attempted to reach has blocked your access

Comment: Also You suggested to open firewall what are the ports need to open  in the firewall i believed its 80, 443

Comment: @MohanBabu I was also getting the [same error](https://i.imgur.com/DowGjCi.png). To resolve this, I created a new VNET, function app and configured private endpoints and vnet integration again and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer I am setting up the same Hopefully I get the good result Thanks again